# VueJs input previsualization, does not change my data inside FileReader listener

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm new to VueJs and currently designing a image picker component. I'm struggling with the file uploaded event, as my mutable properties doesn't want to update inside the event listener.

There's a part of the template code:

```
<input @change="handleUpload" type="file" :name="imageName" />
<img :src="mutableImageString" alt="Image" class="img-responsive" />
```

And the logic :

```
handleUpload: function (e) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var file = e.target.files[0];

    reader.onload = function () {
        this.mutableImageString = file;
    }
    if (file) {
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
},
```

mutableImageString isn't updated, however if I take it out of the onload event, it's updated but with an empty value. Any idea? Thanks!

PS: Sorry about my poor english :c

Comment: It's `this` context problem.Inside the `onload` event, `this` is not bound to the Vue Object.

Comment: It works, thanks! I referenced the current instance in a var and everything is ok :)